# Are these type of "Horizonal" wall mounts safe for hanging a guitar with a gigbag

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, acoustic-guitar, maintenance, storage

I did read this thread [Storing guitar in a gig bag and hanging from a wall hook](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/48758/storing-guitar-in-a-gig-bag-and-hanging-from-a-wall-hook). It concluded with a "don't hang with a gigbag, it becomes a big barrier between playing the guitar often and keeping it there untouched".

So my problem's that Dust here where I live accumulates way too fast. I had my guitar outside the gigbag on a floor stand for just 6 hours, and there was so much dust. So storing without a gigbag is not an option for me.

Because of space constraints, I'm having to wall mount the guitars (1 Acoustic, 1 Electric). So I'm looking for what kind of mount I should go for.

This kind's what Im seeing at the moment: is it advisable to go with this? (My primary doubt's about truss rod problems with this)
[image]
[image]

I've never had hands on with a headstock-mount and so am not sure if the guitar would fit in it with the gig bad. I'm assuming it won't. Or are there any other type of mounts other than these two? (I'm not looking at cases because the barrier they put is much higher than a bag for me). My electric's bag is much thinner than a typical gig bag if that helps, although acoustic's bag's the same regular one.

Answer (score 1):

I've had guitars - acoustic, electric and basses all hanging from headstock hooks for many years. Not had any problems with any. In your situation, I'd have a lightweight sheet, probably shaped in some way, to keep the dust off, but make it moments from lifting off the wall and playing.

Not used the sort in the pics, but can't really see advantages over headstock hooks, properly screwed into the wall.

Comment: Not exactly an advantage, but what im seeing with these is that I can keep the guitars with the gigbags. Ill try the sheet idea

Comment: If you're intent on keeping them in gigbags, which will discourage you from getting them out and played as often, get a gigbag with a loop by the head - or fix one on - and just use an ordinary coathook. What's simpler?